# Text gets cut on PDF

Tags: javascript, html, css, html2pdf

I am using [this](https://github.com/eKoopmans/html2pdf) library to convert my HTML to PDF. I have got the process going but when I download the PDF which is 11 pages, in some pages the paragraphs and input fields gets cut in half at the end of the page. The size of the PDF can increase or decrease based on the input of the user before the print function is executed.

Is there a way to make sure that the page does not get cut off. The library I am using allows me to setup page breaks manually but the size of the page for me is dynamic. I cannot use this feature.Based on another StackOverflow post I did this

```
div{
        page-break-inside: avoid;
    }
```

However, this did not work at all.

Comment: You may add html2pdf-specific page-breaks to your document by adding the CSS class html2pdf__page-break to any element (normally an empty div).

Answer (score 0):

Use [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-pdf) might help you

```
var fs = require('fs');
var pdf = require('html-pdf');
var html = fs.readFileSync('./test/businesscard.html', 'utf8');
var options = { format: 'Letter' };

pdf.create(html, options).toFile('./businesscard.pdf', function(err, res) {
  if (err) return console.log(err);
  console.log(res); // { filename: '/app/businesscard.pdf' }
});
```

Comment: I am using server side conversion

Comment: @greenn what's your backend implemented on?

Comment: Sorry I meant to say "Client side conversion" . I am using Nodejs.